# How can i hide an element by clicking anywhere except on that element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i’m using jQuery’s toggle method to hide/show a page element when another page element is clicked on.

```
jQuery('a#mobile-search-icon).click(function(){
    jQuery(‘#searchBox’).toggle('slow');
});
```

but in addition to that, if the user clicks anywhere on the document except for that element, i’d like that element to fadeout. what’s a line of code to use for that?

my pseudo code would read something like,…

```
$(‘anywhere except #searchBox’).click(function(){
    $(‘#searchBox’).fadeOut();
})
```

i know there’s a jQuery not selector but i’d prefer to use something else. the not selector would be too processor intensive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Comment: There is even a community wiki answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975

Answer (score 1):

Check the whole document for clicks. If the target of a click isn't your element, do what you gotta do.

```
$(document.body).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') != 'searchBox') {
        $('#searchBox').fadeOut();
    }
})
```

Echoing John Smith for completeness:

```
$(document.body).not("#searchBox").click(function() {
    $('#searchBox').fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a ! operator in that if conditional? Since he wants to click anywhere except the element. Oops, looks like you changed it while i was commenting ;)

Comment: @EricGuan yessir, I was fixing that as you commented :) thanks

Comment: Also can be used `on()` function created exactly for nodes comparison. ref: http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$('body').on('click',function()
{
    $('.notwanttotriggerhideclass').fadeOut();//hide your element
}) ;
```

and then return false on the selector you do not want to hide:

```
$('.notwanttotriggerhideclass').on('click',function()
{

    return false;

});
```

or detect the class on the body on click function and hide your class:

```
$('body').on('click',function()
{
    if ($(e.target).attr('class') != 'notwanttotriggerhideclass')) 
    {
        $('.notwanttotriggerhideclass').fadeOut();//hide your element
    }

}) ;
```

Comment: Why do you use `on()` function in such carrying notation (i mean $('body').on)('click'.. ) ? Just interesting

Comment: What do you sir mean? @GlenSwift

Comment: If you mean the ) after the on, it was a typo, btw thanks for your revision!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using this behavior when deselecting an input tag, you are looking for the 'blur' event:

```
$( "#searchBox" ).blur(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

This would also fire when the user was using the input tag and presses TAB, for instance, which is super cool.

EDIT: The not so bad way to do this, assuming you are not using an input would be something like:

```
$('body').not("#searchBox").click(function() { $("#searchBox").fadeOut(); });
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on why `.not()` would be "really really bad"?

Comment: @mc01 `.not()` isn't really really bad... this answer used to say something like `'body *'` as the selector. Using `*` is "really really bad"

Comment: Ah ok - that makes more sense :)

Comment: @mc01 - 1 - Wrapping elements for $( "#searchBox" ) will trigger a click and 2- Tab action will not trigger the required behavior, but charlieg is right, the answer stated a ludicrous selector at first :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a "not" such as:

```
$(document.body).not("#searchBox").on("click", someFunction...
```